# a loop in awk command

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file with the following input data:

```
Sample1

Feature 1
A
B
C
D
Feature 2
E
F
G

Sample2:

Feature 1
H
I
Feature 2
L
O
P
```

And I would like to have the following output:

```
Sample1
Feature 1: 4
Feature 2: 3
Sample2
Feature 1: 2
Feature 2: 3
```

So basically I'm trying to count how many elements are in each feature, and for each sample separately

I tried using the following command:

> awk '{if(/^\Feature/){n=$0;}else{l[n]++}}END{for(n in l){print n" :
>   "l[n]}}' inputfile  > outputfile

But it basically gave me the following output (it counted all the features for all samples)

```
Feature 1: 6
Feature 2: 6
```

Can somebody please help me modify this command or suggest another one?

Answer (score 0):

file `summarize.awk`:

```awk
function print_feature() {
    if (feature) print feature ": " n
    n = 0
    feature = ""
}
NF == 0 {                 # empty line. 
    print_feature()         # print the feature summary
    in_feature = 0          # we are no longer counting elements
    next                    # do not print the empty line
}
$1 == "Feature" {         # a new feature
    print_feature()         # print the previous feature summary
    feature = $0            # save this as the new feature
    in_feature = 1          # indicate we are counting elements
    next                    # do not print ... yet
}
{
    if (in_feature) 
        n++                 # count this element
    else                    # or
        print               # print (e.g. "Sample")
}
END {
    print_feature()         # if there is no trailing blank line, print the current feature
}
```

Then

```
$ awk -f summarize.awk file
Sample1
Feature 1: 4
Feature 2: 3
Sample2:
Feature 1: 2
Feature 2: 3
```